# Rewrite one line in one file in entire git history using git filter-repo

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history, git-filter-repo

Just as the title says. Specifically, I want to change the value of a JSON file in the entire history of my git repo like

```
{
...
    "FOO": "yes"
...
}
```

to

```
{
...
    "FOO": "no"
...
}
```

I found similar answers using `git filter-branch`, but given that is a deprecated command, I want to know how to do this with `git filter-repo`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with:

```bash
git filter-repo \
  --replace-content my-file.json \
  --code 'if match: return match.group(0).replace("\"FOO\":\"yes\"", "\"FOO\":\"no\"")'
```

I cannot try it because I have no repo such yours, but you could try it and give me a feedback.

Remember to install `filter-repo` extension as explained at https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/commit/74ea810872b41331ffdbf02cdc2d474c98b88514 .